# Multiple dex files, finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android

**MY LOGCAT DESCRIPTION** :

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Error:Execution failed for task ':XXXX:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 20.04 secs
    Information:1 error

Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**MY GRADLE FILE** :

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MultiDex issue - Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104925/multidex-issue-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug)

Comment: How can i solve this issue ? I am new to Android Studio.

Comment: using any other library modules?

Comment: Please check your dependency it having multiple jar file included

Comment: The dependencies i used are clearly shown in my question

Comment: remove the comment for the first line

Comment: Sorry man i removed the comment but still it's showing the same error.

Comment: using any other library modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple support libraries in your project. You can try below steps :

1. Open your project folder in windows explorer(Windows)/finder(Mac). Check your project's *libs* folder and any support library's (such as *appcompact_v7*) *libs* folder.
2. Check if you have multiple JAR files with same name.
3. If you have multiple JAR files such as *android-support-v4* then remove one of the JAR file
4. Clean project.
5. Run.